# Search function and duplicate questions by new users

Tags: feature-request, duplicates, searching, low-quality-posts

It's simple to notice that so many question asked by **new users** shall be answer by a simple **search query**. I'm asking if shall be possible put a simple banner saying:

> "*wait, **before ask**, why don't try to search your question?* `|Search...|...Ask!|`"

or something  similar to the users with **low reputation** (maybe 10 or less) when they click (or **hover**) the **`Ask Question`** button.

That will help to let more polite this site and inspire new user to search and figure out  before ask and do something that they may don't understand.

Do you like that? What shall be the best banner?

Comment: We already throw 2/3 banners and messages at new users before they can ask a question, so I don't honestly think one more would help much :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Seth mentioned, If you ever posted a question, you will have "experienced the suggestion", to use an euphemism, to search the database. Adding more, or more aggresive signs would simply not work.

Another thing is that you use "low-quality-posts" as a tag, which is not a synonym to *duplicate questions* in my opinion. I am definitely not promoting allowing more duplicates, but a good and clearly written duplicate might even add something to the site and evoke other, sometimes better answers. The huge amount of unclear questions however, lacking essential information, many times ignored by the poster from the moment he or she pushes the button; those are the ones we should try to prevent, or get rid of as soon as possible once they are posted, in my opinion.

Comment: I didn't know what @seth explain, tx for response. I flag also as low quality post because as you say the primary question isn't the fact of duplicates question, but the unclear ones that "usually" are also duplicate of better formatted ones.